# Trying to cache npm installs between builds on Azure Devops

Tags: npm, azure-devops, npm-install

I'm trying to configure my pipeline to cache npm between builds.
My pipeline.yml looks like this

```
variables:
  npm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm
  
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
    path: '$(npm_config_cache)'
    cacheHitVar: 'CACHE_RESTORED'
    restoreKeys: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)"'
  displayName: 'Cache npm'

- task: Npm@1
  condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')
  inputs:
    command: 'install'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run lint'
  displayName: 'Lint checking'
```

This works fine up until the npm run lint and then it fails.
However the cache key is found and the cache is restored.
The condition line evaluates to false which is also correct.

If I force the npm install then the lint line works.

Any ideas what the difference between restoring the cache and forcing an npm install would be?

Or any ideas of how else to get this to work?

Comment: "Fails" how? Gives an error? What error? You need to provide as much **specific** detail as possible when asking for help. Post the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip - I should have been way more specific.
Basically this doesn't work for anyone else who is trying this.
This isn't the way to cache npm install :) There just doesn't seem to be a good way to do this between builds.
You can cache the .npm folder but that doesn't really speed builds up much if at all - probably due to Azure caching npm registries and high network speeds internal to Azure

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, so I got a suggestion. Look at the variables of your pipeline. See the system.debug variable ? Set it to true. Now, Azure will show usually much more info about what happens in your pipeline. If the linting fails, maybe you find more information. Now adjust your question with the new found diagnostics at hand here.